# Does "Change my registration" make sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm an international student. I'd like to drop one of my courses and sign up for another one instead. In that case, is it okay if I email my advisor as follows:

"I want to talk about my registration. I signed up for the *** course this semester with your approval, but I would like to take another course instead."

I don't want to make any mistake when it comes to the email to my professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the sentence `I want to talk about my registration` to `I am sending this email regarding my course registration.`

```
    I am sending this email regarding my course registration. I joined for the * 
course this semester with your approval, but now I would like to change my course .
```

Comment: No!  *signed up for* is correct. Do not change it to *joined for*  and don't say "change my course." OP's "take another course" is fine.  If anything it could changed to "register for a difference course instead"